# Trim an SQL primary int key and then append some string using Notepadd++ regex

Tags: notepad++

I have a primary key that is `varchar(20)`. I want to add the string "`en`" to the front and then trimming off some digits. E.g initial key: `12345678901234567890` after trimming and adding `en` it becomes : `en_12345678901234567`.
The problem is I have over 20,000 rows in my table with similar primary key. Is there a way to use the Notepadd++ regex to get this done fast? Especially the find and replace functionality?

Comment: Yes there is, you have to show us a little portion of your file and how it would be after the replace.

Comment: `select 'en_'||the_key from the_table`